# How do you find out which item changed when you observe on a list in ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-components

Inside my component.js I am observing on a component property below..

```
valueObserver : function(){
  console.log('which item changed??')
}.observes('list.@each.isChecked'),
```

How do I find out which Item isChecked has changed?

---

Complete component code is below

```
Ember.Component.extend({
  user: undefined,
  list: undefined,
  init: function() {
    this._super();
  },
  visibilityChanged: function() {
    if(this.get('isVisible')) {
      var _this = this;
      var account = this.get('accountService').get('account');

      this.get('user').getLists(account.get('uid'))
        .then(function(response) {
          var items = response.map(function(item) {
            item.isChecked = false
            return item;
          });
           _this.set('list', items);
        });
    }
  }.on('init').observes('isVisible'),

  valueObserver : function(){
    this.get('list').forEach(function(item) {
      if (item.get('isDirty')) {
        // Item has changed
      }
    });
  }.observes('list.@each.isChecked')
});
```

Comment: You likely need a lower level component -- one for each item in the list -- on which you can implement your observer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a hacky way to achieve similar functionality - if the list item is an Ember model you can look for which items are 'dirty' (i.e. their content has been changed by the user but not saved).

```
valueObserves: function() {
  this.get('list').forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.get('isDirty')) {
      // Item has changed
    }
  });
}.observes('list.@each.isChecked'),
```

However, I would not recommend that approach as it's an unnecessary performance detriment and has limited use cases.

Instead, as Oren suggested, you should probably utilize something like a collection view in or in place of your component. That collection view will have an item view for each list item. In the item you can observe `isChecked` and send an action to the component (or just call a method on the component) and pass the item view's content (the list item).

### Alternative Approach

An alternative would be to use an action to set the isChecked property.

```
{{#each item in list}}
  // This could even be a checkbox with the checked attr bound
  <button {{action 'toggleCheck' item}}>Icon</button>
{{/each}}
```

This will send the item to your controller where you can set isChecked and you have immediate access to the item:

```
Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    toggleCheck: function(item) {
      item.toggleProperty('isChecked');
      // Now do whatever you wanted to do
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Was trying to avoid `views` in general as they are getting deprecated.. 
As my list would be small and limited, I can check `isDirty`. I will let you know.`

Comment: @drucan Walker, I updated my question.
The `valueObserves` seems to be get called immediately after `_this.set("list", items)` and gives up an error indicating `item.get` is undefined.

Comment: Then your items are probably not Ember Objects or models. I updated my answer with a slightly different approach.